# How do you find on socket.io > 1 the namespace you are in?

Tags: socket.io

So I'd like to create a special namespace where admin can review every other user.

However I don't find a proper way of getting namespace.

The closest I've got too was to use  `socket.handshake.headers.referer` which gave me `http://localhost:3000/admin` but I find it ugly and guess there is a better option.

Comment: you will find it in `socket.nsp.name`

Comment: @mk12ok `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

At the server side you will find it in `socket.nsp.name` and at the client side you will find it in `socket.nsp`.

Example:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

io.of('/some-namespace').on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a client connected to: ' + socket.nsp.name);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing socket.io - custom namespace</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="socketio"> not connected </h1>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io('/some-namespace');
        socket.on('connect', function() {
           document.getElementById("socketio").innerHTML = "connected to " + 
               socket.nsp;
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```